# C++ namespaces basic usage

Tags: c++, namespaces

In the example below, is it necessary to use namespace A{} in the source file or is it redundant as it is already been done in the header file?

```
// header file Foo.h

namespace A
{
    class Foo
    {
        Foo();
    };
}

// source file Foo.cpp

#include "Foo.h"

namespace A
{
    Foo::Foo() {}
}
```

Comment: You may find that `namespace A;` is an easier way of doing this as it doesn't indent the entire rest of the file.

Comment: It's also much more readable as you get larger projects. Please continue this practice.

Comment: @tadman `namespace A;` is not proper syntax. What is it supposed to mean?

Comment: @uneven_mark Guess it's an incomplete using statement

Comment: @raven Yeah `using namespace A;` would work as long as there are no name collisions with the global namespace.

Comment: @uneven_mark My bad, I forgot the `using` prefix.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's necessary, but you can do the following instead:

```
// source file Foo.cpp

#include "Foo.h"

A::Foo::Foo() {}
```